# RecyclerView doesn´t keep items scrolled at bottom when softkeyboard pops up

Tags: android, listview, scroll, chat, android-recyclerview

When I focus on an edittextview on my chat activity, the recyclerview doesn´t keep the items stacked at the bottom when resizing the view. Previuosly with a ListView was working. I´ve tried any stackFromEnd, reverseLayout parameter.

Basically I want the same behaviour as any chat: whatsapp, telegram, etc.

Somebody has any idea why does it happen?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same situation, and this is how it is fixed:
Use `mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd` method **in code**. Setting in **XML is not respected** by android (in my situation).

```
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: `mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` works for me. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what i search